# Quick methods to make a shapefile/feature not m-aware?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, batch, measurements

Just wondering if anyone knows of a quick method to disable m-aware shapefiles/features? Searching Geonet, ArcDesktop help documents have proved unfruitful.

I'm currently doing copy features and changing it in environments. I could save a ton of time if I disable this in one go.

Anyone else have experience with this?

Comment: Do mean you're already doing this in batch mode and want to go faster?

Comment: No I'm currently running 'copy features' GP tool one at at time which allows me to reexport the shapefile and disable the m-aware value in environments tab.

Comment: You can right-click the copy features tool, choose Batch, fill in the grid for all your runs, set the environment, and execute all runs back-to-back: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/a-quick-tour-of-batch-processing.htm

Comment: Simply change m flag in environment setting s.